# laravel | How to access session array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I am passing an array to a view from my controller.

**Here is the controller function:**

```
$notification = array(
            'message' => 'Welcome Admin!', 
            'alert_type' => 'success',
        );
return redirect('/home')->with('notification', $notification);
```

**In my view:**

```
<script>
  @if(Session::has('notification'))//this line works as expected

    var type = "{{ Session::get('alert_type', 'info') }}";
   //but the type var gets assigned with default value(info)
    switch(type){
        case 'info':
            toastr.info("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
            break;

        case 'warning':
            toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
            break;

        case 'success':
            toastr.success("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
            break;

        case 'error':
            toastr.error("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
            break;
    }
  @endif
</script>
```

as you can see there's clearly something wrong with the way I am trying to access the array value in `var type = "{{ Session::get('alert_type', 'info') }}";`

**EDIT- 1** : 
I tried doing

```
var type = "{{ Session::get('notification')->alert_type, 'info' }}";
switch(type){
    case 'info':
        toastr.info("{{ Session::get('notification')->message }}");
        break;

    case 'warning':
        toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('notification')->message }}");
        break;

    case 'success':
        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('notification')->message }}");
        break;

    case 'error':
        toastr.error("{{ Session::get('notification')->alert_type }}");
        break;
}
```

but now I get an error saying

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)

can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep your PHP and Javascript code seperated. Use `data` attributes in your HTML and fetch the values in your Javascript code instead.

For example this HTML code (I use `json_encode` to support line breaks):

```
<body {{ Session::has('notification') ? 'data-notification' : '' }} data-notification-type='{{ Session::get('alert_type', 'info') }}' data-notification-message='{{ json_encode(Session::get('message')) }}'>
    // ...
</body>
```

Then in your JS file:

```
(function(){
    // Don't go any further down the script if [data-notification] is not set.
    if ( ! document.body.dataset.notification)
        return false;

    var type = document.body.dataset.notificationType;
    switch(type){
        case 'info':
            toastr.info(JSON.parse(document.body.dataset.notificationMessage));
            break;

        case 'warning':
            toastr.warning(JSON.parse(document.body.dataset.notificationMessage));
            break;

        case 'success':
            toastr.success(JSON.parse(document.body.dataset.notificationMessage));
            break;

        case 'error':
            toastr.error(JSON.parse(document.body.dataset.notificationMessage));
            break;
    }
})();
```

You can shorten your JS by doing this:

```
(function(){
    // Don't go any further down the script if [data-notification] is not set.
    if ( ! document.body.dataset.notification)
        return false;

    var type = document.body.dataset.notificationType;
    var types = ['info', 'warning', 'success', 'error'];

    // Check if `type` is in our `types` array, otherwise default to info.
    toastr[types.indexOf(type) !== -1 ? type : 'info'](JSON.parse(document.body.dataset.notificationMessage));

    // toastr['info']('message') is the same as toastr.info('message')
})();
```

---

Read more on: [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks for showing me this way but your answer didn't work for me because I was passing an array into session. so I did `{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}` and It works (see my answer), I will try to do your way with this little correction

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `{{ Session::get('message') }}`

try `{{ Session::get('notification')->message }}` and `{ Session::get('notification')->alert_type }}` respectively.

Your session message returns the array, you will need to use the array keys to get the message not the keys directly.

Comment: okay But I get an error  **Trying to get property of non-object** Here is what I did  `var type = "{{ Session::get('notification')->alert_type, 'info' }}";
`

Answer (score 0):

Okay after taking hints from @milo526 answer I did some more research and found the solution. @milo526's solution tries to access the array as an object so Laravel quacked. I did this and it works now!

```
var type = "{{ Session::get('notification')['alert_type'], 'info' }}";
switch(type){
    case 'info':
        toastr.info("{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}");
        break;

    case 'warning':
        toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}");
        break;

    case 'success':
        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}");
        break;

    case 'error':
        toastr.error("{{ Session::get('notification')['message'] }}");
        break;
}
```